# Right or Left Option in Walkthrough at IGN

Tags: the-witcher-2

I am playing the Witcher 2 on PC. The game presents a lot of choices. To make the right decisions on weapons, I sometimes visit walkthroughs. While reading through a walkthrough at [IGN.com](http://www.ign.com/wikis/witcher-2/The_Dungeons_of_the_La_Valettes), I came across the site saying (Left) or (Right) and two variations.

As @skovacs1 points out, they are in the captions to the image. Note that in the second line, the OP states that there will be a slight variation based on if I go left or right.  Is this something that I should note? Does it affect my gameplay?

Comment: can you provide a link to an example in the walkthrough?

Comment: Going over the walkthrough, the only things I can find matching your description are the image captions. Of all those that I see, the images+captions do not depict variations, but progressive steps with the (Left) image depicting a situation immediately preceding the situation in the (Right) image or related tips like (left)gargoyles like to mob you (right)you need to break the seals as part of the quest. If you see something different, you will need to provide more information in order for us to answer your question.